# Append results from one column into results of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Consider the following table

```
color   old_color

red     dark red
blue    navy blue
red     light red
green   green
```

How do I extract a distinct list of values from both columns so the result would look like:

```
red
blue
green
dark red
navy blue
light red
```

This is basically merging the results of the following two queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT color FROM colors;

SELECT DISTINCT old_color FROM colors;
```

How can I go about writing this into a single statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT color FROM colors
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT old_color color FROM colors
) A;
```

Here is a script to test this:

```
use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS colors;
CREATE TABLE colors (color VARCHAR(20),old_color VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO colors VALUES
('red','dark red '),
('blue','navy blue'),
('red','light red'),
('green','green');
SELECT * FROM colors;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT color FROM colors
UNION SELECT DISTINCT old_color color FROM colors) A;
```

I tried it out in MySQL 5.5.12 on my PC

```
mysql> use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS colors;
CREATE TABLE colors (color VARCHAR(20),old_color VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO colors VALUES
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS colors;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT color FROM colors
UNION SELECT DISTINCT old_color color FROM colors) A;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE colors (color VARCHAR(20),old_color VARCHAR(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO colors VALUES
    -> ('red','dark red '),
    -> ('blue','navy blue'),
    -> ('red','light red'),
    -> ('green','green');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM colors;
+-------+-----------+
| color | old_color |
+-------+-----------+
| red   | dark red  |
| blue  | navy blue |
| red   | light red |
| green | green     |
+-------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT DISTINCT color FROM colors
    -> UNION SELECT DISTINCT old_color color FROM colors) A;
+-----------+
| color     |
+-----------+
| red       |
| blue      |
| green     |
| dark red  |
| navy blue |
| light red |
+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Awesome! Appreciate taking the time to test it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT newtable.*
FROM    
    (SELECT color FROM colors
    UNION 
    SELECT old_color FROM colors) 
AS newtable
```

UPDATE by @RolandoMySQLDBA 2011-08-24 13:46 EDT

Your answer works also on my sample data. Here is the output:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT newtable.*
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT color FROM colors
    ->     UNION
    ->     SELECT old_color FROM colors)
    -> AS newtable
    -> ;
+-----------+
| color     |
+-----------+
| red       |
| blue      |
| green     |
| dark red  |
| navy blue |
| light red |
+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You get a +1 from me as your answer is essentially the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the color of both column in two queries, union the result, and output the distinct colors:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tmp.color FROM (
    SELECT color FROM colors
    UNION
    SELECT old_color as color FROM colors
) as tmp
```

Comment: `UNION` instead of `JOIN` perhaps?